# Recently upgraded my flutter version to the latest stable version now some apps won't run

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This is what I get when I try to run flutter debug
[image]

This is the file I don't understand
[image: The file where the issue comes from]

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028977/android-material-design-sample-code-giving-missing-resources-errors - Accepted solution was to update android studio

Comment: @MichaelHorn I am not using andriod studio for this other apps are working I fear the problem might be with the packages I'm using

Comment: You might still try it - at the very least, you can try [updating your android toolchain](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager)

Comment: @MichaelHorn I updated it and tried to debug directly from Andriod studio same problem. Also the toolchain is up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue was from a package I was using (flutter_paystack), checked the GitHub issues and found a solution. https://github.com/wilburt/flutter_paystack/issues/124#issuecomment-1152890758

Answer (score 0):

Change **targetSdkVersion** in defaultConfig block works for me.

In path: project_folder/android/app/build.gradle

Comment: My targetSdk is 31

Comment: Have you tried removing gradle cache & running flutter clean ?

Comment: Yes I have, I'm still getting this I'm working on 3 apps and 2 apps are giving this error but one works