# Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface</macro>'

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having a problem with running my Android app:

> Can't determine type for tag '?attr/colorSurface'

[image]

Comment: I have same issue. It started happening when play market (and android studio by default) started requiring targetSdkVersion 31 or more. Old projects are compiling fine. Also this new created projects (with 31 level) doesn't start on all my phones (they are old ~ 5-6 android veresion). Quick work around may be - is to create project based on old project with less sdk version (29 e.g.) but this doesn't solve the issue with high sdk level projects. Play market requires it now.

Answer (score 167):

That is caused by `1.7.0`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

You better stick to `1.6.0` till they fix this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
```

Comment: I also came up with this solution after some trial and error. Thanks for the exact version, I was sticking with 1.0.0 only.

Comment: Downgrade is not a solution

Comment: Downgrade is the solution because there are some type of resource conflict...

Comment: It happens also with `com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0`

Comment: I am getting 
Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'
I searched for implementation 'com.google.android.material but couldn't find any line of code

Comment: Update other required dependencies as well 

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.7.0

Comment: Another day, another ridiculous dependency issue on Android :-/ Thanks!

Comment: Happens on 1.9.0 as well...

Comment: It happens also with com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0

Answer (score 54):

In your *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file, where the "dependencies" section is, paste this:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
```

in this section. And remove old strings with the same text and other number versions. In my case:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'    
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

It has worked for me.

Source: *[:app:mergeReleaseResources Can't determine type for tag #33926](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33926)*

Comment: Also, try to update Android Studio. I updated it, and now default new projects from Android Studio works fine. Without an error you described.

Comment: Thanks! Changing material back to 1.6.0 solved the issue

Answer (score 34):

I upgraded the Android Gradle plugin to 7.2.2 and the problem was solved. Try updating Android Studio too.

Answer (score 27):

### Rationale

To expand on the existing answers, the [release notes for Material Components for Android 1.7.0](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.7.0) mentions that they have updated the minimum requirements for your project (emphasis mine):

> #### New minimum requirements for your app's project:
>
> - ***Update to [Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version 7.2.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)***
> - Update to [Gradle version 7.3.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)
> - Update to [Java 8 (version 1.8)](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features)
> - Update to [Android Studio Chipmunk, version 2021.2.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#agp-studio-compatibility)

This is also mentioned in their [(updated)](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/cdc781dde60cc1cf04e0e538f0e5a823f10d5554) [Getting Started guide](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#5-gradle-agp-and-android-studio) (again, emphasis mine):

> #### 5. Gradle, AGP, and Android Studio
>
> When using MDC-Android version `1.7.0-alpha02` and above, you will need to make sure your project is built with the following minimum requirements, **in order to support the latest build features such as XML `macro`**:
>
> - [Gradle version 7.3.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)
> - [Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version 7.2.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)
> - [Android Studio Chipmunk, version 2021.2.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility)

### Updating the Android Gradle Plugin

You can update the Android Gradle plugin as follows:

#### Gradle `plugins` DSL

The plugin declaration can be found in the top-level `build.gradle`/`build.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
plugins {
    // Or "com.android.library"
    id("com.android.application") version "7.2.2" apply false
}
```

#### Buildscript classpath

Update the AGP `classpath` dependency (usually in the top-level `build.gradle`/`build.gradle.kts` file):

```kotlin
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2")
```

Comment: this one is a proper fix instead of the accepted answer which is talking about workaround

Comment: I tried this, then error: This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 2021.2.1 or newer.

Comment: This is the proper solution and others are just hacks...Thanks

Comment: @GeneCode Seems that you either have an old version of the IDE, or something else is borked entirely ¯⁠\⁠_⁠(⁠ツ⁠)⁠_⁠/⁠¯

Answer (score 5):

For Flutter User with this issue this is how you solve it::

**Goto : build.gradle**
change  `"classpath 'com.andriod.tools.build:gradle:5.6.0'"`

to

`"classpath 'com.andriod.tools.build:gradle:<latest version>'"`

in my case :: `classpath  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'`

**then goto :: android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

then change

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.3-all.zip`

to

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-<latest>-all.zip`

in my case `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip`

Answer (score 4):

In order to get over with this, upgrade to the latest Gradle version as well as the latest Android Studio.

I was also facing this issue, and I followed these steps:

- Upgraded Android Studio to [Android Studio 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (Dolphin) | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
- Gradle version to 7.3.1 in project *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)*
- Kotlin version to 1.7.20 in project *build.gradle*
- **targetSdkVersion** and **compileSdkVersion** to 33
- the latest version of dependencies in the app's *build.gradle*

And the project is perfectly working fine now.

Answer (score 4):

1. Update your Android Studio
2. Upgrade your classpath to

   ```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
   ```

Answer (score 4):

In my case it happened to change from gradle version 7 to version 6.8 so my solution was adding this code in `/app/build.gradlew`:

```
dependencies {


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'

    implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0') {
        version {
            strictly '1.6.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Update your *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file as below:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'`

It will fix the issues. Remember v7.3.x won’t fix the issue, so stick to 7.2.1 as of now.

Comment: It works! I've updated to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'` and also updated gradle wrapper to 7.4

Comment: @Zhomart Thanks, after 8 days I am able to fix this shit, I tried every solution on internet and these versions worked.

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded the Android Gradle plugin >= 7.1.0 and the problem was solved.

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0"
```

Comment: This was plagiarised from [Akinyemi Jamiu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191324/cant-determine-type-for-tag-macro-name-m3-comp-bottom-app-bar-container-colo/74334795#74334795). And made ungrammatical in the process.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by:

1. Adding in `build.gradle`:

   ```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
   ```
2. adding `android:exported="true"` in Manifest

Comment: Under which block did you add `android:exported="true"`?

Comment: In activity block

Answer (score 2):

Android Gradle Plugin   up to 7.2.0
Gradle  up to   7.3.3
it work for me, see pic blow

[github dicr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54ECl.png)

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle(:app),

Updating, compileSdk and targetSdk to 33 helped me(from 32).

Answer (score 1):

After wasting two hours and ruining my mood, the solution was simply upgrading my Android Studio version.

Most probably you are using an older version, like [Android Studio 4.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (Arctic Fox) or something like that. Upgrade to [Android Studio 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (Dolphin) or something higher.

And yes in the Dolphin version, it will give the error of 30.0.3, but don't worry. It gives you an attached link to install the 30.0.0 SDK in the console itself, so chill and keep developing.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade all libraries to latest version. Don't downgrade all libraries versions. Just update distributionUrl to the latest version too in *gradle-wrapper.properties* like this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just go to this build.gradle and change your dependencies to this version:

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'**
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I needed to amend the Gradle and main project manifest.

Gradle changes:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'

compileSdkVersion 31
targetSdkVersion 31
```

Android Manifest under activity: Add this :

```
android:exported="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I deleted the code below and wrote it as follows, and it was solved.

Code before modifying:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```

Code after modifying:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by replacing `implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'` instead of `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'` in `build.gradle(:app)`

Answer (score 0):

First, in the Gradle build file, change the implementation from 1.7.0 to 1.6.0.

Next, open the colors file and change the color of the tag (#) which has 7 digits to a 6 digit tag.  Because usually the default color of tags on Android Studio is sometimes 7 digits or 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you start a new project and you haven't updated Android Studio in a while. You might get a message like below

[image]

Update your project as recommended and build your project again. If that does not resolve the issue, create a new project after the update (if working on a new application).