# Suddenly can't determine type for tag error

Tags: java, android

Today I suddenly got error:

```
Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface</macro>'
```

Out of nowhere. Invalidate cache & restart & clean does not work. Checkout to old version which 100% worked before, does not work.

Also already tried the solution from other thread:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'    
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

Changed into this & clean & rebuild does not work, same error.

AndroidStudio Version is Bumblebee 2021.1.1
targetSDKVersion is 31, everything's fine until just now.

Thank you

Comment: Did you perhaps updated gradle or other tools? Or maybe it is used by 3rd party library which is deprecated?

Comment: This looks to be a common issue with a recent update, as several users have posted questions about it since yesterday. This is the only one with an answer, so far: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74191324.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by:
Update AGP to 7.2.0
Gradle to 7.3.3
appcompat v.1.5.0
material design 1.7.0

Updating AGP seems a must for my case

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the same issue. I resolved it using the following combination in Gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
```

Also, I was using this version of `KOTLIN`

```
kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
```

AndroidStudio Version is Bumblebee 2021.1.1 | Patch 3