# android error: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface</macro>'

Tags: android

I was having some problems with a project on my android studio. so I deleted that project and start a new one but then following error shows up when I try to run the app.

```
Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface</macro>'
```

it's very strange because I did not make any changes on to the hall project.
I tried to delete and recreate the project but it's the same error.

Comment: You might have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74205872), and the one I link in the comments there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updating android studio is the solution for me

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem too,
Use below versions in `build.gradle` to fix

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to fix this is by changing the :

implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1"

implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0"

with

**implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1"**

**implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0"**

this solve the problem for me ^_^'