# getting "Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'"

Tags: android

I recently tried to migrate my code from Android 8 to Android 10. After migration the build keeps failing and the following error messages are thrown-
"Can't determine type for tag ' attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall'
Can't determine type for tag '?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall'".

From a previously asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191324/cant-determine-type-for-tag-macro-name-m3-comp-bottom-app-bar-container-colo) I followed the two actions that were instructed on it.
But After doing the the implementation as mentioned in the responses of the above question, the error still persisted and a new error generated along side it.

I have also tried defining the macro in the xml file but the error still persists.
AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <!-- Define the macro -->
        <macro android:name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape"
            tools:ignore="ExtraText">?attr/shape AppearanceCornerSmall</macro>

        <!-- Use the macro -->
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="@m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">
```

Build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-fstack-protector-all"
            }
        }

        minSdkVersion 19
        //  targetSdkVersion 29

        applicationId "com.dcpl.printfromonbase"

        versionName "2.2"
        versionCode 6

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases' }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable false
        }

        customDebuggableBuildType {
            debuggable false
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

    }

}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    // implementation  //fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    implementation project(path: ':WorkpathLib')
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
}
```

Comment: I am getting same error it was working fine untill yesterday now same error persists. Have you fixed the error? there is no such line in my code  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'

Answer (score 13):

Decrease the version of material library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
```

Another way is to upgrade your Gradle plugin

Comment: In my case I had to go down to `1.6.0`. Versions are listed here for reference: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material?repo=google

Answer (score 5):

## The possible cause

This is a dependency issue with the [Material (`com.google.android.material`) library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material?repo=google), which in newer versions depend on a newer version of Gradle, as explained by a maintainer here:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/3423#issuecomment-1561471465

> [...] Versions 1.7.0 and later of the material library require at minimum Android Studio Chipmunk (2021.2.1), Gradle version 7.3.3, and Gradle plugin version 7.2.0 [...]

The possible reason this happened in the first place is that you are using a newer version of Android Studio and its libraries that by default will add this library as a dependency which won't work with your version of Gradle.
In my case, this was added during the addition of an activity with the "blank" template, which added this as a dependency to my build.gradle file, which caused the combined values.xml to contain invalid tags.

## The fix

Your solution is to upgrade Gradle to ^7.3.3 or newer if you need Material 1.7.0, 1.8.0, or newer.

## The workaround

Simply downgrade it instead to version 1.6.X if you don't really need the new features. You may not need the features in an RN project, so you are safe to downgrade to version 1.6.0 as upgrading Gradle usually is a large migration that is likely to break other things.

Replace the following in your `build.gradle` file, or search the project for uses of the `com.google.android.material` dependency and check the versions:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0' // or any version higher
```

And replace the version so it reads:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
```

Comment: Thanks  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0' workd for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found the menu entry "Tools > AGP Upgrade Assistant..." in Android Studio. I used this to upgrade the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) to version 7.3.1 and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your gradle and distributionUrl

Answer (score 1):

In the build.gradle(:app) file, decrease the version of material library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because of the react-native-screen module.
I fixed it this way:
go to node_modules/react-native-screens/android/build.gradle file and

dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0' => 1.6.0 (change version)
...
}