# Getting an "Can't determine type for tag" '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">? on Unity build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build, apk

When i try to get an apk for my game it gives this error.

stderr[
C:\Users\keski.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ba619997594d18d7dfcb030ed6d764ea\jetified-com.google.android.material.material-1.9.0-alpha01\res\values\values.xml: Resource and asset merger: Can't determine type for tag '?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':launcher:mergeReleaseResources'.

> C:\Users\keski.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ba619997594d18d7dfcb030ed6d764ea\jetified-com.google.android.material.material-1.9.0-alpha01\res\values\values.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall'

I tried upgrading my Gradle but it didn't help

Comment: Please refer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191324/cant-determine-type-for-tag-macro-name-m3-comp-bottom-app-bar-container-colo

Comment: i saw that question and tried the suggested solution but it didn't work.

Comment: I am getting same error did you fixed that?

Comment: i have enabled jetifier, and then i deleted everything in the assets/plugins/android folder, restarted unity, forced resolve and solved that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue, and downgrading the dependencies didn't work for me. As a result, I started a new project in Android Studio Giraffe using Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.kts). I simply copied the files into the new project, as well as the dependencies, adjusting them to the new Gradle format. The project worked without needing to downgrade dependencies.